# Detect when a particular application (not mine) becomes visible / not visible to the user

Tags: android

<strike>I am currently trying to write an app that will change certain settings automatically (turn off sound, etc) when an application becomes active and to revert back to the original settings when the application is no longer active.</strike>

**EDITED**
Sorry, I believe I explained the question poorly. I am currently trying to write an app that will be able to detect when a certain application (for example, youtube app) becomes visible to the user, meaning that the user has just launched/navigated to the youtube app.

When I detect this, I want to perform certain setting changes, such as turning off the phone's sound (I have already figured this part out). And then, when I detect that the youtube app is no longer visible to the user, I want to restore the settings back to what they were.

What I want to know is the mechanism to detect when any application at all (not my application) becomes visible / not visible to the user.

Kind of like what the app Tasker does.

I am trying to figure out how it accomplishes this. There does not seem to be any broadcast receivers that will notify on applications becoming active. One way that I can think of is to create a service that constantly polls the currently running tasks.. but this seems like it will give very bad performance.

Is there any alternative that someone may suggest?

Thank you in advance

Comment: By active, do you simply mean if the application is visible, i.e. the user hasn't pressed home or navigated to another activity?

Comment: What do you mean by "when application becomes active/inactive"?

Comment: Sorry, I probably did not describe that properly. What I mean is I would like to have some way of detecting when any application (not my application) becomes visible, and when it is no longer visible. So for example, if a user opens/navigates to the youtube app, my app will automatically turn on the phone's sound to maximum, and when they exit the youtube app or moves to another app, my application will restore the old sound settings again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the list of running processes and do something with it.
You can do this using the following code:

```
ActivityManager actMngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = actMngr.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (RunningAppProcessInfo pi : runningAppProcesses) {
    //Check pi.processName and do your stuff
    //also check pi importance - check if process is in foreground or background
    if (pi.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
        //DO YOUR STUFF
    }
}
```

Please note that to list processes you need the GET_TASKS permission.
You can do this by adding this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: Hello pandre, thanks for the answer, that is actually what I would like to perform, but, my question is actually detecting when to execute the code you just gave. I was thinking along the lines of constantly polling the running proceses list with a service, but that seems like it will give bad performance.

Comment: Hi @Coins that's what I do in my app - I periodically poll the list of processes. You can use a Handler to execute the code I posted

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by active? An application is either running or terminated, and you have 2 hooks to change the behaviour of the application [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29)  and [`onTerminate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate%28%29)

On the other hand, an application has different components, like activities, and an activity has a more complex [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) with similar hooks.